# Is there a tool that can tell me how a subset is different from a whole (in terms of features)

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection

Is there a tool/technique where we can specify a subset of tuples (of feature values that are real numbers) from an overall set and ask how this subset could be anomalous? (i.e., what are the key feature values that distinguishes this subset, and how)

For example: Feature average F1 in subset is 2 stddev higher than in overall set

Another exmaple: 40% of F2 values are non-zero in subset, but only 10% are non-zero in overall set.
etc. ...

Answer (score 0):

If your data is numerical, you can judge based on mean,median,stdev, etc.

You can also use clustering algorithms such as K-means and compare the average distance for both datasets.

You can also use Hierarchical Clustering and compare the datasets visually. Here is a good python code to visualize the dendograms.

[SciPy Hierarchical Clustering and Dendrogram Tutorial](https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/08/26/scipy-hierarchical-clustering-and-dendrogram-tutorial/)